# Time complexity about Maximum subarray

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation, maximum-subarray

I recently came across a function called the strawman algorithm which the pseudo code looks like this:

```
StrawmanSubarray(A):
  Initialize bestsum = A[0]  
     For left=0 to n-1:
        For right = left to n-1:
           Compute sum A[left] + . . . + A[right]
           If sum > bestsum: bestsum = sum
```

The time complexity is Θ (n^3), and I don't quite get where is the 3rd n comes from to get Θ (n^3)?

Comment: How many operations can computing $A[left]+...+A[right]$ be?

Comment: You're wrong; it matters. It is _exactly what causes your confusion_.

Comment: You have `right-left-1` sums in the line that starts with `Compute `. This line is repeated by  the inner `for` for `right = left to n-1` and the outer for repeats its content for `left=0 to n-1`. So, the number of sums is $\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\sum_{r=l}^{n-1}(r-l-1)=\frac{n (n^2 - 3 n - 4)}{6}$. However, the line `Compute` could be implemented in such a way that each iteration does only one sum. In this case the number of sums is $\sum_{l=0}^{n - 1}( \sum_{r=l}^{n - 1} 1) = \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}$.

Comment: @BearAqua ok sure, let's assume the array length is n=8?

Comment: @plop sorry I am still a newbie, how do you get the formula n(n^2-3n-4)/6? thanks

Comment: @sctts-lol I just [put a computer to do it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum+r-l-1+for+r%3Dl+to+r+%3Dn-1%29+for+l%3D0+to+l%3Dn-1). To do it by hand there a many ways, one way is to use the first two formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples).

Comment: thank you very much